# What does ". script" do?

Tags: powershell

What will the following lines of PowerShell code do?

```psh
Set-Location D:\Utilities\AZ 
. D:\Utilities\AZ\Uti.ps1
```

I am sure about he first line that it changes the path but not really sure about the second.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: (it will run the script, by the way, but did you really need to ask this question?)

Comment: Yeah, I cannot run it ..otherwise I would have ..Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

The `. C:\path\to\script.ps1` part is known as "Dot Sourcing".

When you run a script without the dot, the contents of the script is executed in its own scope (the `Script` scope), and so any variable or functions defined inside the script will not persist after the script is done executing.

When you dot source a script (like in your example), the contents of the script is executed in the the callers scope, and functions defined inside the script will persist even after it has run.

Quote from the [`about_Scripts`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847841.aspx) help file:

```
SCRIPT SCOPE AND DOT SOURCING

    Each script runs in its own scope. The functions, variables, aliases, and
    drives that are created in the script exist only in the script scope. You
    cannot access these items or their values in the scope in which the
    script runs.

    To run a script in a different scope, you can specify a scope, such as
    Global or Local, or you can dot source the script.

    The dot sourcing feature lets you run a script in the current scope instead
    of in the script scope. When you run a script that is dot sourced, the 
    commands in the script run as though you had typed them at the command 
    prompt. The functions, variables, aliases, and drives that the script 
    creates are created in the scope in which you are working. After the script
    runs, you can use the created items and access their values in your session.

    To dot source a script, type a dot (.) and a space before the script path.

    For example:

        . C:\scripts\UtilityFunctions.ps1

    -or-

        . .\UtilityFunctions.ps1
```

Answer (score 3):

`Set-Location` changes the working directory of the script to the given folder. The second statement [dot-sources](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847841.aspx) the PowerShell script, i.e. it loads the content of the file and runs it in the current context (see section *SCRIPT SCOPE AND DOT SOURCING* of the help topic I linked to).

Since you said you cannot run the script, you're most likely getting the following error when dot-sourcing it:

```
File D:\Utilities\AZ\Uti.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is
disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
At line:1 char:2
+ . <<<<  D:\Utilities\AZ\Uti.ps1
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

This means that the execution policy for PowerShell scripts on your system is set to `Restricted`. Use `Get-ExecutionPolicy` to verify that, and use `Set-ExecutionPolicy` to change it:

```psh
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope User
```

or just

```psh
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

if you have administrative rights.

If `Set-ExecutionPolicy` fails, the execution policy is probably defined with a group policy, in which case you need to talk to your admins about it.

See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847841.aspx) for a more detailed explanation of execution policy scopes.